# Is there any alternative of Heroku for ruby on rails app to deploy live?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, heroku, deployment

***I wanted to deploy my ruby on rails app live I already try Herkou &
 Aws. So is there any alternative of this?***

Comment: What are you optimizing for (price, performance, documentation, easy to use)? Why do you want to change, what do you dislike at Heroku or AWS? What are your application`s requirements (number of requests, database types, load balancer)?

Comment: Actually, I need to know more platform for deploying web application so btw, I also used Heroku and AWS as well

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy your ruby app on your VPS-server. It's so simple as configure development environment. And there are many information and solution of many issues for that.

You can deploy your ruby app on any server/hosting. Better if that use linux OS, but it can be something else.

If it's that you want, you can read this great article about deploy:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/deploying-a-rails-app-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-capistrano-nginx-and-puma